# Shed Foundation with Concrete Piers -Not Square

Tags: shed

I’m feeling unsure of what to do:
I’ve been working on my shed foundation and floor. Due to the slope in my backyard, I used concrete piers with wet set j bolts and post bases. I set my beams in the post bases and using joists to frame out the floor. I just bolted up my beams and rim joists and rechecked square and my diagonals are out of square by two inches!!! The lengths have been verified. Because everything is anchored down, I can’t just use a hammer to knock it into square.

Any suggestions? If I proceed forward, will that just be an absolute headache?

Comment: Pictures are always helpful. You're using metal brackets designed for posts to grab onto your beams? Elaborate on "everything is anchored down." It sounds like the brackets are laid out fine, but a few nails at the metal post base brackets are preventing you from squaring it up. (Typically joist to beam connections are flexible enough to allow rotation, so you would just slide one beam parallel to the other until everything is square.)

Comment: And "bolted up" is a steel construction idiom. We're talking about a wood floor here, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to the question: "If I proceed forward, will that just be an absolute headache?"

Floor sheathing comes in square cut sheets that aren't going to align with the edges of your floor framing. Fix your our-of-squareness if it doesn't require much effort, as fixing those sheet edges may be a bigger headache.